# xcode array of Arrays and UITableViews

Tags: nsarray, uitableview, hierarchical-data

I am new to Xcode and Objective-C programming and need some help.

I am looking to create a basic program for the iOS that uses hierarchal-data and 2 separate `UITableViews`. I want the second `UITableView` to be populated by an array that is passed between `viewControllers`, based on which cell/row is selected in the first `UITableView`.

The program compiles but I get a `SIGABRT` error when running the program. Can someone help me fix the `SIGABRT` and pass the `mainArray` to the second `tableView`?

Here is how far I have gotten.

My code:

**ArrayTableViewController.h**

```
@interface arrayTableViewController : UITableViewController
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *mainArray;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *secondArray;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *thirdArray;
@end
```

**ArrayTableViewController.m**

```
#import "ArrayTableViewController.h"
#import "table2.h"
@implementation arrayTableViewController
@synthesize mainArray, secondArray, thirdArray;

-(void) viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
mainArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects: secondArray,     thirdArray, nil];
secondArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects: @"123", @"456",     nil];
thirdArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects: @"78", @"90", nil];
}



- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
return [mainArray count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}


cell.textLabel.text = [mainArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

table2 *table2Controller = [[table2 alloc] initWithNibName:@"table2" bundle:nil];
table2Controller.arrayForDisplay = [[mainArray objectAtIndex: [indexPath row]] objectAtIndex:1];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:table2Controller animated:YES];

}

@end
```

**table2.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface table2 : UITableViewController
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *arrayForDisplay;
@end
```

**table2.m**

```
@implementation table3
@synthesize arrayForDisplay;
```

Then the same cell configuration style that was used in `ArrayTableViewController.m`

**Edits:**

After making the necessary changes, when I run the program and select a row, I get a `SIGABRT` error at the following line.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
@autoreleasepool {
    return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([ArrayTableAppDelegate class]));
}
}
```

What would you recommend? Should I turn off `ARC` and call my own releases? so that I can get to the second `tableView`?

Comment: If you are getting the crash after selecting a row, then it means you have made some mistakes in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method. Can u pl. show that code?

Comment: didSelectRowAtIndexPath: method has been edited to the current code

Comment: See my Edit 2 for `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`.

Comment: I tried this and am still getting a SIGABRT when selecting a row. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**First mistake:**

In `viewDidLoad` method, you have created the `mainArray` with `secondArray` and `thirdArray` as elements even before you allocated those arrays.

**Second mistake:**

In `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method:

Check the line `cell.textLabel.text = [mainArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];`

Actually the `textLabel` expects a NSString value to set. But you are setting an array.

**Edit:**

Set the value to textLabel as following:

```
cell.textLabel.text = [[mainArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]] objectAtIndex:0];
```

Actually this will set the first value of the array. But that it depends on your requirement.

**Edit 2:**

`arrayForDisplay` is an array variable but you are setting a string variable to that in the statement

```
table2Controller.arrayForDisplay = [[mainArray objectAtIndex: [indexPath row]] objectAtIndex:1];
```

Do it as follows:

```
table2Controller.arrayForDisplay = [mainArray objectAtIndex: [indexPath row]];
```

Comment: Yes it does for the exception of the cell configuration. How would I configure the tableCell to show the items of the array?

Comment: Great answer that helped a lot thank you. However now the SIGABRT has made its way to the appDelagate. Please see "EDITS" added to the question? any suggestions?

Comment: or would you have/know where i can find a sample source code of what i am attempting to do?